# Why does the mdframed-box not adhere to the columnwidth in a multicol-environment?

Tags: macros, multicol, mdframed, column-width

Since it is impossible, or at least *really* hacky, to split a command over two arguments, I'd rather use a macro with a new environment to achieve a faster typesetting experience and consistent look.

I intend to put a box around a minipage which is smaller/narrower than the columnwidth that it is placed in, hence my attempt at the new environment.

Then I just ran into the next problem: the box set with mdframed does not seem to adhere to the columnwidth.

=> Why does the first box have that faulty width? Did I make an error or did I overlook something?

(Ironically, the faulty version has the nicer vertical spacing before the line with the orange text. This is something that I wanted to fine-tune later-on, but apparently already did so inadvertently.)

## Screenshot of MWE

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
multicol,
blindtext,
mdframed,
}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\newenvironment{envstuff}[2]{%
\begin{center}
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\columnwidth}\sffamily
\centering
\textcolor{orange}{\textbf{Something:}}~{#1}
\par\addvspace{-0.8ex}%
\rule{0.98\textwidth}{0.1pt}\par\addvspace{1ex}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.98\columnwidth}\small\sffamily
{#2}}
{\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{mdframed}
\end{center}}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\huge
Title stuff
\end{center}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Word}

\begin{envstuff}
{Words}{There really are words.
And then some.
AAaaaa bbbb cccc.
}
\end{envstuff}

{\centering
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\columnwidth}\sffamily
\centering
\textcolor{orange}{\textbf{Something:}}~{Words}
\par\addvspace{-0.8ex}%
\rule{0.98\textwidth}{0.1pt}\par\addvspace{1ex}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.98\columnwidth}\small\sffamily
There really are words.
And then some.
AAaaaa bbbb cccc.
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}}\par}


\blindtext[1]

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell from the documentation, a `mdframed`'s default width is the available `\linewidth`, which is why your first box is exactly as wide as the column it is placed inside of. To overcome this, you can use `userdefinedwidth`.

Comment: Better use tcolorbox instead of mdframed.  It is much more powerful.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oooh. Yes, it is! Thank you for the tip! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the following is closer to the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
multicol,
blindtext,
mdframed,
}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\newenvironment{envstuff}[2]{%
\centering
\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=0.95\columnwidth, align=center, innerleftmargin=6pt, innerrightmargin=6pt]
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\sffamily
\centering
\textcolor{orange}{\textbf{Something:}}~{#1}
\par\addvspace{-0.8ex}%
\rule{0.98\textwidth}{0.1pt}\par\addvspace{1ex}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small\sffamily
{#2}}
{\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{mdframed}
}



\begin{document}
\begin{center}\huge
Title stuff
\end{center}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Word}

\begin{envstuff}
{Words}{There really are words.
And then some.
AAaaaa bbbb cccc.
}
\end{envstuff}

\blindtext[1]

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did expect that kind of output. But boy, is that width-usage confusing (for me personally). I will manage somehow, not sure yet if I use that code. But thank you, it solved the question.